# Select in JSTL/JSP returns null to servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jstl

I'm trying to get the value of the selected item in JSP page, when I'm trying it locally it works! but once I published it, it stopped working because it always returns "null" value for the parameter

JSP/JSTL code:

```
    <form action ="SelectedEntity" method ="get">
<label>Please select one of the following entities: </label>
<select name="Entity">
    <c:forEach var = "entity" items ="${entities}">
        <option ><c:out value="${entity}"/></option>
    </c:forEach>
    <input type = "submit" name = "submit" id = "submit" value ="Go">
</select>

</form>
```

and this is the servlet:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        String entity = request.getParameter("Entity");
```

This is always returning null .. can someone help me with that?

Comment: When I changed it to "Post" it seems to be working.. Why?!

Comment: Try using  <option value="${entity}>${entity}</option>

Comment: In the page directive of your jsp place this attribute isELIgnored="false"
Example : <%@ page isELIgnored="false" %>
check if this works